# $T_{f}(a,x)$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,b]$ whenever $f$ is absolutely continuous $[a,b]$. (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let
$$T_{f}(a,x) = \sup \sum_{j=1}^{n}|f(t_{j}) - f(t_{j-1})|$$
be the *total variation* of $f$ on $[a,x]$. I want show that:

> $T_{f}(a,x)$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,b]$ whenever $f$ is absolutely continuous $[a,b]$.

**My attempt.** We need to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that:

$$\sum_{1}^{m}|T_{f}(a,b_{k}) - T_{f}(a,a_{k})| < \epsilon$$
whenever
$$\sum_{1}^{m}|b_{k} - a_{k}|<\delta.$$

Note that
$$\sum_{1}^{m}|T_{f}(a,b_{k}) - T_{f}(a,a_{k})| = \sum_{1}^{m}T_{f}(a,b_{k}) - T_{f}(a,a_{k}) = \sum_{1}^{m}T_{f}(a_{k},b_{k}).$$

Choose $\delta$ that satisfies the absolutely continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $\displaystyle \tilde{\epsilon} < \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{m+1},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$. So,

$$\sum_{1}^{n}|t_{j}-t_{j-1}|<\delta$$
implies
$$\sum_{1}^{n}|f(t_{j}) - f(t_{j-1})|<\tilde{\epsilon}.$$
for any partition of $[a_{k},b_{k}]$. Therefore,

$$T_{f}(a_{k},b_{k}) = \sup \sum_{1}^{n}|f(t_{j}) - f(t_{j-1})|<\frac{\epsilon}{m}.$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{1}^{m}T_{f}(a_{k},b_{k}) <\epsilon.$$

---

That makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. A slick way to do this is to note that since $f$ is absolutely continuous, we have

$1).\ T_f(a,x)=\int^x_a|f'(t)|dt,$

and so $T_f$ is absolutely continuous (use absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral).

$1).$ follows from the following facts:

$2).\ T_f$ is nondecreasing, so $\int^x_aT_f'(a,x)\le T_f(a,x).$

$3).\ |f(x) - f(y)| \le |T_f(a,x) - T_f(a,y)|$, so $|f'|\le |T'_f|=T'_f.$

$2).$ and $3).$ combine to give

$4).\ \int|f'|dt\le T_f.$

On the other hand, $f$ is absolutely continuous, so

$5).\ \sum^n_{j=1} |f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j)| \le |\sum^n_{j=1}\int^{t_j}_{t_{j-1}} f'(t)dt|=|\int^{b}_a f'(t)dt|\le \int^{b}_a |f'(t)|dt$.

Suping over the LHS of $5).$, we get

$6).\ T_f(a,x)\le \int |f'(t)|dt$.

$4).$ and $6).$ together give $1).$

Comment: Nice proof! ${}$